# Task Pane minimum width for 0365 add-ins

Tags: office365api, office365-apps

Is there any way I can set the minimum width for task pane in which my add-in will render while developing an add-in for Outlook desktop using Apps for Office template of visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

No, setting the width is not currently supported.